# my questions about Write a Java program to construct a LinkedList

Tags: java

Write a Java program to construct a LinkedList and do the following tasks:
(a) Insert 5 elements into list.
(b) Add one node at first position
(c) Add one node at last position
(d) Add one node at second position
(e) Print the contents of list using ListIterator.
(f) Remove first, third and last element from the list
(g) Change value of second node.
(h) Print list without using list iterator

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you are looking something like:

<code>
    LinkedList<String>  linkedlist = new LinkedList<String>();
        // add 5 elements
        linkedlist.add("Item1");
        linkedlist.add("Item2");
        linkedlist.add("Item3");
        linkedlist.add("Item4");
        linkedlist.add("Item5");        
        System.out.println("List =["+linkedlist+"]");
        /*Add First*/
        linkedlist.addFirst("Item0");
        System.out.println("List =["+linkedlist+"]");
        //Add Last
        linkedlist.addLast("Item6");
        System.out.println("List =["+linkedlist+"]");
        //Add second
        linkedlist.add(1, "Item02");
        System.out.println("List =["+linkedlist+"]");
        linkedlist.removeFirst();
        linkedlist.remove(1); // remove 3rd
        linkedlist.removeLast();
        System.out.println("List =["+linkedlist+"]");
</code>
```

Comment: LinkedList has to be coded manually is what OP wants---not the library class! So you receive -1 from me.

Answer (score -1):

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
list.add(note1);
list.add(node2);
.
.
.
list.addFirst(note6);
list.addLast(note7);
list.add(1,note8);
```

Try to do the rest on your own ;)

If you need to implement your own linked list, I suggest you start with a class, representing an element:

```
 public class Element{
    public String value;  // value of the element
    public Element next;  // next element
}
```

And then you should create a linked list class like:

```
public class MyLinkedList{
   public Element first; // represents the first element of the list

   /*
   methods for adding/deleting elements
   */
}
```

Comment: LinkedList has to be coded manually is what OP wants---not the library class! So you receive -1 from me.

Comment: That's not what the question says... It should be defined better!

Comment: Still the method declarations are missing! So,still the downvote remains!

Comment: I know they're missing. But he should try to implement them by himself, don't you think? We still haven't seen any of his code, that means he didn't even try to solve the problem. And I'm ready to help if someone show at least some interest to solve it.